# GitEye crashes because of oxygen-gtk when pressing "Git Files"

Tags: git, gtk, giteye

I downloaded GitEye from http://www.collab.net/downloads/giteye and started it on my Linux Kubuntu 14.4. Then I selected my git project. This worked until I press on the "Git Files" register: GitEye crashes:

```
$ ./GitEye
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

(process:11473): Gdk-WARNING **: locale not supported by C library

(process:11473): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Fontconfig warning: ignoring en_us_8859_1: not a valid region tag
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
java: /build/buildd/gtk2-engines-oxygen-1.4.5/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion `!_button._widget' failed.
```

I think it might be the reason that I use oxygen-gtk for GTK2: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339174

After I switched oxygen-gtk for GTK2 to Raleigh in my System Settings, GitEye hasn't been crashing anymore - however it looks atrocious.

I read through the bug report, but I did not understand what I could do to fix this issue. What can I do?

**BTW:** Is this the right site or should I ask the question at Linux&Unix or at askUbuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in KDE: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339174

There is a patch there, or the easier option is the workaround:

For oxygen, edit the normally already existing file "/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" and change
    GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1
into
    GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0